# CSS Div inside a Div

Tags: html, css

I'm currently stuck on a problem, I have tried using ".test" "#test" and "test" but nothing seems to select what I'm trying to work on. Below is the code I'm working on.

HTML

```css
#test {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div id="test">
        <img src="pictures/furniturepic1.jpg" alt="Furniture Picture" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code works fine! what is you want select?

Comment: have you linked your css file?

Comment: Everyone here hates the idea of having to guess what you're working on. If you want an answer you must ask your question correctly https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It seems like css file is not linked. nothing wrong with css. May be adding background color would be easier to check whether it is applying or not.

Answer (score 1):

if your css file is linked properly  with your html file. this one is going to work for you.

here is the css code:

```
div#content div#test {
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
}
```

or

```
#content #test {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

both is going to work for you

Comment: No it's not. I don't see any element with `class="content"`

Comment: sorry. but i didn't get it. would you please explain why this will not work?

Comment: Sure - Your selector should be `div#content div#test` because the question has `<div id="content">`

Comment: i have already updated it.